# Fetch mysql array in selected chunks and pass through socks

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, socks

I have this simple code. The problem i m facing is, I have a list of websites in a table called **Domain**, i want to fetch all the rows in an array(or maybe select rows) and then split this array into 60 rows each chunk. e.g 1 Chunk = 60 Rows. Then check each chunk under 1 sock. After 60 rows are checked under 1 sock, get 2nd Chunk and get other sock and keep doing until end.

Since i can't use 1 sock twice, advice will be needed what should i do to check if same sock is not used twice. (fetch socks from db maybe? Add sock in db after its checked?)

This is the code below...

```
    <?php

$proxies = array();

$proxies[] = '193.165.37.134:45301';
$proxies[] = '82.124.237.100:44356';

if (isset($proxies)) {  // If the $proxies array contains items, then

$proxy = $proxies[array_rand($proxies)];    // Select a random proxy from the array and assign to $proxy variable

}

$timeout = 5;
$splited = explode(':',$proxy); // Separate IP and port
if($con = @fsockopen($splited[0], $splited[1], $errorNumber, $errorMessage, $timeout)) 
{

$ip = $splited[0];
$port = $splited[1];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM domain ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$id = $row['id'];
$url = $row['url'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);                                                             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);  
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$status = do_some_work($result);

$sql = "UPDATE domain SET status = '$status' WHERE id = '$id' ";
mysql_query($sql);

}
}
?>``
```

Any help will be appreciated. THanks

Comment: instead of create chunk you can select 60 rows from database using limit

Comment: In your code where you have devided the array result into chunks ?